# CSS grid with fixed sidebar

Tags: css, css-grid

I need a fixed header and sidebar on my site, beyond a central div. The sidebar should have a scrollbar of its own, just like the central div. I thought that grid layout would be the way to do this, but I can't avoid the body to display a common scrollbar, instead of each container displaying its own.

How should I do it? Is grid indeed the simpler solution?

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #add790;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

nav {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 1em;
  min-height: 0;
}

#divMain {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <nav>
    <p>Navigation</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
  </nav>
  <div id='divMain'>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Set a height to each container that needs the scrollbar and use `overflow-y: scroll`

Comment: @ManojKumar The height of each container is the height of the screen minus the height of the header, which is dynamic, depending on the user's font size. So, how to accomplish what you suggest?

Comment: Using JavaScript. CSS cannot detect user font size or browser height.

Comment: @ManojKumar There was indeed a CSS answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background-color: #add790;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 20%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

article {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <nav>
    <p>Navigation</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text.</p>
  </nav>
  <article>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
    <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  </article>
</main>
```

Answer (score 7):

Accepted answer is not a `css-grid` based solution. So my answer is here.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

header {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  background-color: #add790;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

nav {
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <p>Navigation</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <p>Some text.</p>
</nav>
<main id='divMain'>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
  <p>Here too there should be a local scrollbar.</p>
</main>
```